# adding mp4 play back to webview using html5

Tags: android, html, webview

cant seem to get webview to allow mp4 playback from my html5 i get audio just no video i just get a play symbol. im using my website that uses mp4 videos with button playback. I just want the app to mimic the site in webview but mp4 wont play.

WebView

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:id="@+id/activity_main"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   tools:context="com.example.mdr.instantapptest.MainActivity">

 <WebView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:id="@+id/web1" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Java

```
package com.example.mdr.instantapptest;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    WebView webb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web1);
    webb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webb.loadUrl("http://mywebsite.html");
    webb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    }
  }
```

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.mdr.instantapptest">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-
permission>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
   </application>

  </manifest>
```

all this is very new to me but been working on this for 2 weeks still no video
just want the website to work on a tablet or phone and play mp4 videos from my host as it does on a web browser. as of now everything works its just the videos have play symbol ond nothing when clicked on tablets i get audio.

Comment: Does it work on Chrome on the same device?

Comment: maybe the video codec of that particular video are not supported

Comment: it works on all browsers just running the html but video wont play inside apk get audio just no video ill take a screen shot and upload

Comment: https://ibb.co/kWzv0a

Comment: this is inside browser  https://ibb.co/idOutv   I can goto link in browser on device and works fine just not when i load in webview as apk